# Data Structure Serialization (Django)

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

Good day. Tell me how can I convert and process the data received by the API into one model (one database table). The structure is like this:

```
{
    "id": 1234567,
    "name": "Another Name",
    "price": 0,
    "responsible_user_id": 123456,

    "custom_fields_values": [
    {
        "field_id": 500047,
        "field_name": "Gender",
        "field_code": null,
        "field_type": "select",
        "values": [
            {
            "value": "Male",
            "enum_id": 267077,
            "enum_code": null
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The object has dynamically added fields (custom fields), can I not create a separate model for custom fields, but bind them in some way to the main model and how can I process the data for saving?

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [django.db.models.JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField), if you are using the one of the supported DBMS.

First update the Lead model to include a JSONField.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import JSONField

class Lead(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    responsible_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    custom_fields = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In your view, process the data as follows (assuming you're using Django Rest Framework):

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Lead

class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'

@api_view(['POST'])
def create_lead(request):
    data = request.data
    custom_fields = data.pop("custom_fields_values")
    data["custom_fields"] = custom_fields
    serializer = LeadSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```